# Using comparison operators in where clause in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that contains list of messages with a count. Count 0 means all messages are read and Count > 0 means that there are n number of unread messages. I want to get either the read records, unread records or both the records with a status type ('Read', 'Unread', 'Both'). I am using the following SQL query:

```
DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(10)
SET @Status = 'ALL'
SELECT *
FROM Messages
WHERE
    (UPPER(@Status) = 'READ' AND UNREAD = 0) 
    OR (UPPER(@Status) = 'UNREAD' AND UNREAD > 0) 
    OR (UNREAD >=0)
    )
```

I have also tried with this SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(10)
SET @Status = 'ALL'
SELECT *
FROM Messages
WHERE 1 = (
    CASE WHEN UPPER(@Status) = 'READ' AND UNREAD = 0 THEN 1
         WHEN UPPER(@Status) = 'UNREAD' AND UNREAD > 0 THEN 1
         WHEN UPPER(@Status) = 'ALL' AND UNREAD >= 0 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END
    )
```

But every time, the returned result set contains only the records which has Count > 0. What am I doing wrong?

Table Structure is like :

```
 ChatGroupId     Unread
---------------------------
      1             0       --When all messages are read
      2             50      --When some of the messages are unread
```

Output should be:

When @Status = '**READ**'

```
 ChatGroupId     Unread
---------------------------
      1             0       --When all messages are read
```

When @Status = '**UNREAD**'

```
ChatGroupId     Unread
---------------------------
      2             50      --When some of the messages are unread
```

When @Status = '**ALL**'

```
 ChatGroupId     Unread
---------------------------
      1             0       --When all messages are read
      2             50      --When some of the messages are unread
```

Comment: If you show us a table structure, some sample data and expected output it would help (and/or a sql fiddle) - I have a suspicion you're overcomplicating this quite a bit but it's difficult to be sure without additional information.

Comment: Updated. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Messages
WHERE
    (UPPER(@Status) = 'READ' AND UNREAD = 0) 
    OR (UPPER(@Status) = 'UNREAD' AND UNREAD > 0) 
    OR (UPPER(@Status) = 'ALL')
```

If your search string `@Status` = `'READ'` and value of column `UNREAD` = `0` It will select all rows where `UNREAD` = `0`.

If your search string `@Status` = `'UNREAD'` thats mean you want to select all unread messages where value of column `UNREAD` > `0`.

Otherwise if you want to get all the rows `'READ'` and `'UNREAD'` you could check if `@Status` = `'ALL'` and you don't need to check column `UNREAD` anymore, because no care what value will be in `UNREAD` column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one

```
DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(10)
SET @Status = 'ALL'
SELECT *
FROM Messages
WHERE 1 = (
    CASE WHEN UPPER(@Status) = 'READ' AND READ = 0 THEN 1
         WHEN UPPER(@Status) = 'UNREAD' AND UNREAD > 0 THEN 1
         WHEN UPPER(@Status) = 'ALL' AND UNREAD >= 0 and read>=0 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END
    )
```

if you have additional column read.. you can go for above one ..

if not..

Remove the  ">=0" in all and please try this

```
WHERE
    (UPPER(@Status) = 'READ' AND UNREAD = 0) 
    OR (UPPER(@Status) = 'UNREAD' AND UNREAD > 0) 
    OR (UPPER(@Status) = 'ALL')
```

Comment: @Adi why did you copy - pasted my answer after edit?